# Sprite Kit UIActivityIndicator won't stop animating

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uiactivityindicatorview, sktextureatlas

I'm trying to pre-load an array of texture atlases during which a UIActivityIndicator is displayed. Once the textures are loaded I want to stop the activity indicator using the .stopAnimating() method. I've inserted breakpoints and found that the compiler does get to the .stopAnimating() method, but nothing happens...the indicator continues...

What am I doing wrong here?

```
class Menu: SKScene {

var activityInd: UIActivityIndicatorView!

 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    activityInd = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .WhiteLarge)
    activityInd.center = CGPointMake(self.frame.midX, self.frame.midY)
    activityInd.startAnimating()
    scene!.view?.addSubview(self.activityInd)

    SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([saxAtlas, saxIdleAtlas, drumAtlas, drumIdleAtlas, pianoAtlas, pianoIdleAtlas, bassAtlas]) { () -> Void in
            self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
        }
}
```

Comment: try adding `self.activityInd.removeFromSuperview()` and see if that gets called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually when you want to stop an activity indicator you just call `removeFromSuperview()` as it's no good to have a static activity indicator sitting there doing nothing, and that's all that `stopAnimating()` gives you.

You should also be calling this method on the main thread, since `preloadTextureAtlases` is a background task and just about anything prefixed with 'UI' needs to be run on the main thread.

```
SKTextureAtlas.preloadTextureAtlases([saxAtlas, saxIdleAtlas, drumAtlas, drumIdleAtlas, pianoAtlas, pianoIdleAtlas, bassAtlas]) { () -> Void in

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.activityInd.stopAnimating()
    }            

}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately calling any methods in the completion handler for preloadtextureatlases doesn't work: .removeFromSuperview, .alpha etc all don't work...

Comment: Actually calling it on the main thread does work, but I wan't the activity indicator to stop after the texture atlases have loaded...tried setting up a Bool in the completion handler with an if statement on the main thread, but it seems that I'm unable to call any methods on the activity indicator unless it's in the main thread...even in an if statement it doesn't get called.

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated.